# Use "\return" as "\brief"

Tags: doxygen

For very simple functions I would like to only have a `\return` section, but still show it as brief. (How) Can this be done?

For example:

```cpp
/**
\return The distance.
*/
template <typename R = int64_t>
R distance(const pcg32 &other);
```

this generates no `\brief` in the docs, whereas e.g. this does:

```cpp
/**
Multi-step advance function (jump-ahead, jump-back).
\param distance the distance.
*/
template <typename T>
void advance(T distance);
```

See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? When I understand it correctly you want to show in the brief description the text that normally appears in in the return section.  Only way I can think of is to to get the text as `\brief` and as `return` and set `REPEAT_BRIEF=NO`, otherwise make a complete example showing (in text what you would like to accomplish).

Comment: @albert Thanks. I'm on 1.9.1. I want to do exactly what you state. However, I'd prefer a non-global settings. In pseudo-code, what would be great is if I could set `\return Lorem ipsum \brief == \return`

Comment: I'm not aware of a possibility to accomplish this (and actually I don't see a use case for this either).

Comment: @albert I guess that the only advantage is that one really has a single statement like here, currently either the is no "brief" entry in the class overview (when `\return` is used), or no 'details' entry (when nothing is used), and thus no link to the source. So if one wants both one have to use `\brief` *and* `\return`, which imo somethings leads to repititions.

Comment: This indeed lead to repetitions, but I see no other way and like I wrote before: "I don't see a use case for this either"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the *brief* section is meant to hold single paragraphs, while the \return command actually generates a header along with a paragraph.

In order to avoid changing any global REPEAT_BRIEF settings, I'd suggest a simple macro to be used for this case, e.g.,

- Add the following to the doxygen ALIASES configuration:

```
    "briefreturn=**Returns** "
```

- Use in your description comment like so:

```cpp
/** \briefreturn the value that it returns */
int foo();
```

This would give you a one-line brief that is similar to the multi-line output from `\return`.

Modifying the macro, you can achieve other behaviors as desired, e.g., forcing generation of a *details* section, even when no other details supplied but the return:

```
"briefreturn{1}=**Returns** \1 \details. "
```

This can still be followed by details in the normal manner.  Note that will have a leading ".", though.  (Perhaps some other non-whitespace character can be used instead that is less offensive as a leading sentence character)

Comment: Thanks! What I think is still different is that in this case there is no detailed function description being generated, just the brief (I guess because there are no arguments, nor return)

Comment: Correct.  To force generation of details, even when no section would normally be generated, then you may need to adjust macro and add a dummy `\details` in there somewhere.  I thought this question was more about getting the single-line return into the brief section.  I think forcing the generation of a detailed section is an easier problem.

Comment: It was both in fact. Your solution is great, and I don't think that for such small functions one really needs a detail. But it would be still nice to know how one should do it.

Comment: Note that the question was edited after my last comment to give an example which produces details and brief.  I tested to make sure it worked.  I guess another option would be to use the macro to put in the brief return statement and an actual `return` statement at the same time.  Lots of improvements possible...